# Are there infinitely many finite fields of non-two prime order with consecutive quadratic residues?

Tags: finite-fields, quadratic-residues

I'm curious whether there are non-two prime numbers $p$ where such that fields of order $p$ have $\left\{1, 2, \dots \frac{p-1}{2}\right\}$ as their quadratic residues.

This paper [Real Analysis is a Degenerate Case of Discrete Analysis](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/real.pdf) by Doron Zeilberger was linked in an answer on Stack Exchange and someone commented that taking a large finite field as your universe leads to positive and negative numbers being indistinguishable, since all elements of the field are expressible as a finite sum of $1$s. My question is *only loosely inspired by the paper and the comment since I'm not qualified to comment on either of them*.

I'm wondering if there are infinitely many fields where the Legendre symbol and a signum function "line up" ... by having $\{1,2,\dots,\frac{p-1}{2}\}$ be the quadratic residues.

The finite field of order 3 has this property. Here's its multiplication table for the nonzero elements. It's clear if $1$ were considered positive and $2$ were considered negative our property would hold.

```
   1  2
 +-----
1| 1  2
2| 2  1
```

The finite field of order $5$ does not have this property, since its perfect squares are $1$ and $4$.

```
   1  2  3  4
 +-----------
1| 1  2  3  4
2| 2  4  1  3
3| 3  1  4  2
4| 4  3  2  1
```

So, are there finitely or infinitely many finite fields with this property?

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what you mean by $\left\{1,2,\dots,\frac{p-1}{2}\right\}$ in a finite field with non-prime order. I may be missing something, but if $q$ is a power of the prime $p$, aren't the elements $\left\{1,2,\dots,\frac{q-1}{2}\right\}$ simply the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ as $\mathbb{F}_q$ has characteristic $p$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Sorry, I meant a field of prime order where the prime is not $2$ since $1=-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$. I'm afraid I don't understand the rest of your question, but I think in the setting you're describing $\left\{ 1, 2, \dots, \frac{q-1}{2} \right\} $ (where $q = p^k$) would contain duplicates when transported to $\mathbb{F}_p$ .

Comment: That's essentially what I was trying to say -- but if your finite field does have prime order then this answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, not possible. The residues make a multiplicative subgroup; there must be exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ of them, no more. You can check for, say, primes between $3$ and $19.$

For prime $p \geq 23,$ there will be a number of the form $n^2 - n$ **(where $n-1$ and $n$  are consecutive quadratic residues)** between $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $p-1.$ For $p=23,$ $n(n-1) = n^2 - n  = 12$ works. But then $12$ is a residue, and there are too many

For $p=29, $ we take $n=5,$ so $n(n-1) = 20$ is forced to be a residue, too many.

For a pattern, we may take $$n = \left\lfloor \sqrt p \right\rfloor  $$
so that $n$ and $n-1$ are both smaller than $\sqrt p,$ there product is an integer that is now forced to be a residue

Actually, now that I think of it, we may just take $n^2,$ where $n = \left\lfloor \sqrt p \right\rfloor  $ For large enough $p,$ this square (already below $p$) will also be larger than $\frac{p-1}{2}$

Comment: Why would n(n-1) would be always a square? and also, is there any name for the primes that fullfil OP requirement, they would seem to be a simpler prime fields compared to all others.